# dataTAble : reload not working, json not valid?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using last version of dataTable

I delete a row throught an ajax request like this :

```
$.ajax
              (
                  {
                      method : 'POST',
                      //la route (controleur) et le paramètre (id à supprimer)
                      url: url + "/professionnels/deleteProfessionnels/"+id_to_delete,
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success:function()
                      {
                          //console.log(retour);
                          $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

PHP model code :

```
public function deleteProfessionnel($pro_id)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM professionnels WHERE id = :pro_id";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(':pro_id' => $pro_id);

    // useful for debugging: you can see the SQL behind above construction by using:
    //echo '[ PDO DEBUG ]: ' . Helper::debugPDO($sql, $parameters);  exit();
    $query->execute($parameters);
}
```

PHP Controller code :

I arrive in the success function of ajax, but I've got this message :

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

```
public function deleteProfessionnels($professionnel_id)
    {
        // if we have an id of a song that should be deleted
        if (isset($professionnel_id))
        {
            // Instance new Model (Song)
            $professionnel = new Professionnel();
            // do deleteSong() in model/model.php
            $professionnel->deleteProfessionnel($professionnel_id);
            //echo "id=> ".$professionnel_id;

        }

        // where to go after song has been deleted

        $professionnels = $professionnel->getAllProfessionnels();
        //print_r(json_encode($professionnels));
        echo json_encode($professionnels, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

When I test the json result with [enter link description here](https://jsonlint.com/), I have error.

1- Why php returns a not valid json object ?
2- Have I to do all this to reload the table ?

This is the response in js (json object) :

```
    {"0":{"id":"123","nom":"G\u00e9om\u00e8tre","prenom":"Barack","adresse":null,"numero":null,"boite":null
,"cp":null,"ville":null,"mail":null,"telephone":null,"inami":null,"tva":null,"disponibilite":null,"commentaire"
:null},"1":{"id":"128","nom":"G\u00e9om\u00e8tre-expert","prenom":"Barack","adresse":null,"numero":"6"
,"boite":"3","cp":"1300","ville":"Bruxelles","mail":"contact@dubinfo.be","telephone":"0471301253","inami"
:"5533434343","tva":"BE 0832.581.586","disponibilite":null,"commentaire":null}}
```

Comment: Please check in the browser first that whether you are getting valid response with the url you are using in your ajax?

Comment: I tried several times to display the return, no success for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
public function getCoursesForDatatable(){
    $table = 'courses';
    $primaryKey = 'course_id';
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'course_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'course_short_description', 'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'course_is_active', 'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'course_added_at', 'dt' => 3 ),
        array( 'db' => 'course_public_id', 'dt' => 4 )
    );
    // $join_where = "JOIN investors ON course_applications.course_user_id = investors.investor_id";

    $arr = $this->datatable_model->get_rows( $_GET, $table, $primaryKey, $columns );
    $ret = $this->formatArticleData($arr['data']['info']);
    $a = array(
        "draw" => $arr['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $arr['recordsFiltered'],
        "recordsFiltered" => $arr['recordsFiltered'],
        "data" => $ret
        );
    echo json_encode($a);
}

public function formatArticleData($data){
    if(!empty($data)){
        $res = "";
        foreach ($data as $key => $value){
            $res[] =  array(
                    $value['course_name'],
                    $value['course_short_description'],
                    ( $value['course_is_active'] == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive" ),
                    date("d-M-Y", strtotime($value['course_added_at'])),
                    '<a class="ui button mini app-button " href="' . base_url('courses/edit') . '/' . $value['course_public_id'] .'">Edit</a>'
                );
            }
            return $res;
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, {"0":{"id":"123","nom":"G\u00e9om\u00e8tre","prenom":"Barack","adresse":null,"numero":null,"boite":null
,"cp":null,"ville":null,"mail":null,"telephone":null,"inami":null,"tva":null,"disponibilite":null,"commentaire"
:null},"1":{"id":"128","nom":"G\u00e9om\u00e8tre-expert","prenom":"Barack","adresse":null,"numero":"6"
,"boite":"3","cp":"1300","ville":"Bruxelles","mail":"contact@dubinfo.be","telephone":"0471301253","inami"
:"5533434343","tva":"BE 0832.571.586","disponibilite":null,"commentaire":null}}

Comment: Your data returned from server is in different format than what is required by  datatables. Here is sample data from my server

{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[["Angular JS","This is a short description for Angular JS Course.","Active","05-Apr-2017","Edit<\/a>"],["Computer Programming","This is a short description.","Active","05-Apr-2017","Edit<\/a>"],["Health Care","This is a health care program.","Inactive","08-Apr-2017","Edit<\/a>"]]}

Comment: I received too TypeError: ajax is null

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try this code to format your data before echoing from server.